# Regex to remove all characters after the pipe excluding newline

Tags: regex

I have the following list of IP and proxies:

```
test:password|123.456.123.12:80
test:password|123.456.123.12:80
test:password|123.456.123.12:80
test:password|123.456.123.12:80
test:password|123.456.123.12:80
test:password|123.456.123.12:80
test:password|123.456.123.12:80
test:password|123.456.123.12:80
```

How do I remove all the text after the | without actually removing newlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for this regex:

```
\|.+
```

And replace with the empty string. `\|` is a literal `|` character, `.` matches any character that is *not* a newline, and `+` means to match the preceding item one or more times.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pM5mI8/1).

Comment: As OP said remove text ***after*** `|`, I think either you should replace with `|`, or change it to something like `(?<=\|).+`

Comment: @AdrianShum that's a good point, and maybe OP can clarify. If OP wants to leave the `|` in place, either of your solutions looks good to me.

Comment: I bet OP actually wanted to have `|` removed too  :P  (though the question was not accurately describing that)

Comment: @adit Great; glad I could help!