# remove characters from the strings matching pattern postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, wildcard

I have some text elements in the column that have a character "|" and the rest right after it I need to get rid of:

```
campaign
abc
fdg|3234
dfr|4567
```

I want it to look like:

```
campaign
abc
fdg
dfr
```

I tried:

```
select replace (data_2_crm.campaign, '_|_', '' ) from data_2_crm
select trim (trailing '.*|' from campaign) from data_2_crm
select trim (trailing '%|' from campaign) from data_2_crm
```

It didn't work. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to remove all characters after the pipe excluding newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770716/regex-to-remove-all-characters-after-the-pipe-excluding-newline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex replacement on the pattern `\|.*$`:

```
SELECT
    campaign,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(campaign, '\|.*$', '') AS new_campaign
FROM data_2_crm;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Use [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
select t.*, split_part(campaign, '|', 1)
from data_2_crm;
```